# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Errors:

1. Could not execute method for android:onCli                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick"
2. Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
3. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference at com.stunner.mobicoach.MainActivity.btnAddData(MainActivity.java:152)

------------------code------------------

```
public void btnAddData (View v){
    String name = etName.getText().toString();
    String surname = etSurname.getText().toString();
    String position = etPosition.getText().toString();
    Person person = new Person(name,surname,position);
    persons.add(person);

    setTextToTextView();
}
```

Comment: Be more clear in your question please

Answer (score 0):

etName or etSurname or etPosition is Null means their object you didn't create

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have find the view by id in your java code. i.e.

```
edtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditBoxId);
```

Check this line for all editboxes, missing this can be the cause of your problem.